# Running powershell through c# recently getting error Access is denied

Tags: c#, powershell, office365

This program has been running successfully for over 4 years. Just recently (8/4/2022), the pscommand version of the program has failed. We are trying to figure out what changed.

We are getting the error "Connecting to remote server outlook.office365.com failed with the following error message : Access is denied. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic." ONLY when dealing with pssession / PSCommands.

Code:

```
public Collection<PSObject> runPSCommand(PSCommand _command, string _commandName, PSCommand _secondCommand = null)
        {
            PSCredential credential = new PSCredential(this.emailLogin, this.emailPass);
            WSManConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(new Uri(this.WSManConnectionURI), this.MSSchema, credential);
            connectionInfo.AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Basic;
            try
            {
                using (Runspace runspace = System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo))
                {
                    PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create();
                    PSCommand remoteSigned = new PSCommand();
                    runspace.Open();
                    powershell.Runspace = runspace;
```

wsmanconnectionURI: https://outlook.office365.com/PowerShell-LiveID

MSSchema: http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.Exchange

Fails at runspace.Open().

We run multiple different type of commands on this program (Connect-ExchangeOnline, Connect-AzureAD, Connect-MSOLService) that are ALL working, it is JUST running the PSCommands that fail.

Tried with powershell as well and it is also failing:

```
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection -Credential Get-Credential
```

With error: "New-PSSession : [outlook.office365.com] Connecting to remote server outlook.office365.com failed with the following error message : Access is denied.
For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic."

Again, this was working for multiple years and JUST started failing. We checked passwords, check logins, tried multiple users.

Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: This question is outside of my skill and experience, but I find it interesting that according to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/current-channel#version-2207-august-03), Version 2207 was released August 3rd, and you discovered your problem August 4th.  Unfortunately, I don't see any changes that get my attention, unless it happened in the "Resolved issues" section where fixing one bug may have created another bug.

Comment: @Darin thank you, your insight led me to what the issue probably was. From this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/exchange-online-powershell-v2?view=exchange-ps we moved from pssession to connect-exchangeonline.

Comment: Glad you were able to find the cause.   It's very frustrating to have something break for apparent reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, Darin lead me to the correct answer, and it was probably deprecation per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/exchange-online-powershell-v2?view=exchange-ps. Apparently PSSession was deprecated, and we had to move the commands over to exchange online.

For those that it might help, our new code is:

```
        public Collection<PSObject> runExchangeCommand(Command _command, string _commandName)
        {
            InitialSessionState initialSession = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
            initialSession.ImportPSModule(new[] { "MSOnline" });
            //initialSession.ImportPSModule(new[] { "ExchangeOnlineManagement" });
            PSCredential credential = new PSCredential(this.emailLogin, this.emailPass);
            WSManConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/PowerShell-LiveID"), "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.Exchange", credential);
            connectionInfo.AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Basic;
            connectionInfo.MaximumConnectionRedirectionCount = 10;
            Command connectCommand = new Command("Connect-ExchangeOnline");
            connectCommand.Parameters.Add(new CommandParameter("Credential", credential));

            try
            {
                using (Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(initialSession))
                {
                    runspace.Open();
                    Pipeline pipe = runspace.CreatePipeline();
                    pipe.Commands.Add(connectCommand);
                    var results = pipe.Invoke();
                    var error = pipe.Error.ReadToEnd();
                    if (error.Count > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (PSObject err in error)
                        {
                            //more logging not sharing that code
                        }
                    }
                    pipe = runspace.CreatePipeline();
                    pipe.Commands.Add(_command);
                    var results2 = pipe.Invoke();
                    var error2 = pipe.Error.ReadToEnd();
                    if (error2.Count > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (PSObject er in error2)
                        {
                            //more logging, not sharing that code
                        }
                    }
                    return results2;
                }
            }
```

I left out logging / catch code because that included some identifying things.

As for creating the command, it boils down to what command you want to run. Here is one example of the runExchangeCommand:

```
        public bool removeCalendarInvites(string email)
        {
            Command removeMeetings = new Command("Remove-CalendarEvents");
            removeMeetings.Parameters.Add("Identity", email);
            removeMeetings.Parameters.Add("CancelOrganizedMeetings");
            removeMeetings.Parameters.Add("QueryWindowInDays", 365);
            removeMeetings.Parameters.Add("Confirm", false);
            Collection<PSObject> results = runExchangeCommand(removeMeetings, "removeCalendarEvents");
```

The command name is only used for logging / identifying what errors were caught in.

Thanks for looking